# ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use vgg16 (button layers) and put my layers for classification task (9 categories).

```
    from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
    model = VGG16(input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                  include_top=False,
                  weights='imagenet')
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    layer = Flatten()(model.output)
    layer = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(layer)
    layer = Dropout(0.2)(layer)
    prediction = Dense(9, activation='softmax')(layer)
    model = Model(inputs=model, outputs=prediction)
```

I'm getting error (before compilling the model):

```
ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inputs` argument of model expects an input layer, but you passed a model object.

Get your input layer by `model.input`.

change your last line to this:

```
   model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=prediction)
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer to help the asker and future visitors understand why this solution might work.